# Line break in rmarkdown pdf table

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to break the text of the header of my table into two rows, but I'm not getting success.
I'm using a code similar to the one below

````
---
output: pdf_document
---


```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE, message=FALSE}
  require("knitr")
  require("kableExtra")
  table = cbind(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))

  kable(table, format="latex", align = "c", booktabs=T, , col.names = c("A", "B"))%>%
    add_header_above(header=c("extremely large name","ok"))
```
````

Can someone help me?

Comment: As far as I know, the pipe table syntax does not support line breaks. I would suggest you look at `pander` package.

Answer (score 2):

Try 4 backslashes \\\\ as a line separator. I think the new line requires 2 backslashes, but they both need to be escaped, so you end up with 4.

kable(table, format="latex", caption = "extremely large name that goes to\\\\second line")